# PHP parent child relation recursion

Tags: php

Hi Folks can you help me with parent-child relation,here is db structure, i think that recursion is necessary.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is array example

```
array(31) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1210 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(56)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(77)
    ["url"]=>
    string(5) "1.png"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#1211 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(77)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["url"]=>
    string(5) "2.png"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#1212 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(223)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(77)
    ["url"]=>
    string(5) "3.png"
  }
```

My goal is to achieve in one element array with all child rows, and array with parents on same level.

Something like this

```
array(31) {
  [77]=>
  object(stdClass)#1210 (4) {
    ["same_level_parents"]=> [1]
    ["child_rows"]   => [44, 56, 115]
  }
```

So id 77 has one same level record (NULL), and 3 children with 44, 56, 115, 
Please can you help me with recursion, i need indexed array with id as a key, and same level parents and children in it.

Comment: Wait, `id ` is null?  I could see `parent_id` being null, but null `id ` makes no sense.  When making a function to build this array, remember you’re asking two different questions:  what are the siblings of x, and what are the descendants of x. So your function should call two different functions to get the answer. If you try to get this in one big recursive function you’d need to differentiate between the two.

Comment: it's null because it's root element, any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: A root element would have a null parent id, not a null id. As I have time I will try to put something together, but I don’t have much free time today

Comment: sure sir working as well, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for this problem. I made it so that you even can give a child children.

To improve readability I renamed the property same_level_parents to siblings.

```
function relationShipTreeArray($array){
    $output = [];
    //Generate output array
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        $output[$row["id"]] = [
            "level" => 0,
            "siblings" => [],
            "children" => [],
        ];
    }
    //Set Current level and childeren of data in the output array
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        //Skip if this is a top level row
        if ($row["parent_id"] === null) {
            continue;
        }
        //Set the level of the current row (parent level + 1)
        $output[$row["id"]]["level"] = $output[$row["parent_id"]]["level"] + 1;
        //Add row to parrent child list
        array_push($output[$row["parent_id"]]["children"], $row["id"]);
    }
    //Set siblings data in the output
    foreach ($output as $key => $row) {
        foreach ($output as $subKey => $subRow) {
            //Skip if main is same as sub
            if ($key === $subKey) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($row["level"] === $subRow["level"]) {
                //When subrow id is not in array, add subrow id to mainrow siblings
                if (!in_array($subKey, $output[$key]["siblings"])) {
                    array_push($output[$key]["siblings"], $subKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

//TEST
$myArray = [
    [
        "id"        => 56,
        "parent_id" => 77,
    ],
    [
        "id"        => 44,
        "parent_id" => 77,
    ],
    [
        "id"        => 115,
        "parent_id" => 77,
    ],
    [
        "id"        => 77,
        "parent_id" => null,
    ],
    [
        "id"        => 1,
        "parent_id" => 56,
    ],
    [
        "id"        => 2,
        "parent_id" => 1,
    ],
];
print_r(relationShipTreeArray($myArray));
```

Comment: same_level_parents also should be array of id's

Comment: need all parent siblings

Comment: @Ambulancelada I added the functionality of siblings to my answer. Let me know if this is wat your looking for :)

Comment: close but some rows have some additional sibling , why you do $output[$row["id"]]["level"] = $output[$row["parent_id"]]["level"] + 1;

Comment: Do you mean by additional sibling that there are siblings missing? $output[$row["id"]]["level"] is the depth on which layer the child is. So for example for one parent with a child that has also child's, the level would be 2 for the last child. You can also call it the Layer, Generation or Level.

Comment: I see the answer is fixed :)

Comment: tnx i will check later

Answer (score 0):

If you’re just looking for parents and immediate children, no recursion is necessary. You can just query the database.

```
// assuming a pdo connection, $db

function allRows($db) {
  return $db->query(‘select * from tableName’)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function parents($db, $id) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(“select a.* from tableName a inner join tableName b on b.id = a.parent_id where a.parent_id = ?”);
  $out = [];
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $out[] = $row[‘id’];
  }
  return $out;
}

function children($db, $id) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(“select * from tableName where parent_id = ?”);
  $out = [];
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $out[] = $row[‘id’];
  }
  return $out;
}

$db = new PDO( ... );  

$all = allRows($db);
$out = [];
foreach($all as $i => $row) {
  $id = $row[‘id’];
  $parent = parents($db, $id);
  $children = children($db, $id);
  $out[$id]  = array(
    "same_level_parents" => $parents,
    "child_rows" => $children
  );
}
```

It also should be possible to do it in a single query, if no recursion is needed (I don’t use Mysql; YMMV):

```
select a.id, group_concat(parents.id) parent_ids, group_concat(children.id) child_ids
from tableName a
left join tableName parents on a.parent_id = parents.id
left join tableName children on on children.parent_id = a.id
group by a.id
```

To find parent siblings, you'd have to go up a level and then find children again, something like

```
with parents as (
    select distinct b.id from tableName a
    inner join tableName b on a.pid = b.pid
),
children as (
    select distinct b.id
    from tableName a
    inner join tableName b on a.id = b.pid
)
select a.id, group_concat(parents.id) parent_ids, group_concat(children.id) child_ids 
from tableName a
left join parents on a.id = parents.id
left join children on a.id = children.id
```

note that records with no parent would need to have a pid of 0, not null.

Another way to approach this problem without using recursion is to build a ***materialized path*** column (look it up, it allows finding all descendants in a single query)

To make all descendants show instead of just children, just make the `children()` function recursive. (Disclaimer, this is off the top of my head; some debugging is probably necessary. Also, typed on a phone so single and double quotes are syntax errors if copied)

```
function children($db, $id) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(“select * from tableName where parent_id = ?”);
  $out = [];
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $id = $row[‘id’];
    $out[] = $id;
    if($child = children($db, $id)) {
      $out[] = child;
    }
    return $out;
  }
}
```

Comment: tnx i will check later i prefere single query solution

Comment: I see from the other thread that you are looking for parent siblings... none of my solutions address that.  I think the mysql group concat gives a comma separated list that you would have to parse if you wanted an array, but that's simple enough using `explode(",",$str)`.  I'll add a query for siblings if I can.

Comment: Added a new query, but it's not tested.

Comment: well query is wrong it won't return parent's siblings

Comment: Yeah, it didn’t feel right. My brain wasn’t wrapping around it right. I changed the CTE query. This should work better. Get your parents parent, and match all the records having the same parent. Note again that you must use 0 as the top level, not null.